# Python: read float32 image into numpy array

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library, geotiff

I have some GeoTiff images which I believe are float32 images and I want to read them using python.

What I have tried:

```
def load_save_test(filename):
    import numpy as np
    import Image
    from shutil import copyfile

    copyfile(filename, "tile.tif")

    arr= np.asarray(Image.open(filename))
    print 'np.count_nonzero(arr)', np.count_nonzero(arr)
    img = Image.fromarray(arr)
    img.save('tile_pil.tiff')
```

But after I open `tile.tif` and `tile_pil.tif` via ImageJ (that support float32 images) I can see some difference.

Also I have checked number of non-zeros after load: `np.count_nonzero(arr) 3`

So what can be the reason of this problem?

[image]

Original image:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8841028/temp/tile.tif

Comment: What happens if you use a test image that is not all black?

Comment: Could you please join the .tif file in your post if possible, so I can try to debug with you  ? :)

Comment: @AlexandreKempf https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8841028/temp/tile.tif

Comment: @mrgloom When I open the file with EyeOfGnome which is the classical image viewer on ubuntu I can see color points and white points with a transparent background. This is completely different from what you showed with your image viewer. 
When I'm saving it into a png (with EyeOfGnome) it give me these points in python also. 
ImageJ give me the same result as you and if I convert it to png I obtain a perfect zeros matrix in python.

Comment: If you expected a black square I would recommend to convert the tif images into png with ImageJ if it's not a big deal :)

Comment: @AlexandreKempf My question is not about viewing but more about real data contained in the image. P.s. in windows default viewer I also see white pixels, but default windows viewer is not suitable for viewing float images.

Comment: @mrgloom Sorry for this visualization parenthesis, but I don't know what is in your image, so I wanted to see it first. 
Are you expecting something in this image ? 
Is there a way to record one perfectly controlled image with the setup you're using to know exactly what you're expecting ? 
I think this can help to know which import method is the best :)